# why quarkus need DB configuration for Build Project

Tags: quarkus

I am really did not understand the concept here and trying to clear what is happening in build time.
My application get built using `clean package` and Now I have different `profile` based on environment. my default profile does not had db connection details. when Jenkins build happen I am not expecting it connect to db or some aws services as most of those are defined in respective profile file. When I do build its keep failing to required all those settings defined.
About JUnit test all of dependencies are mocked and its working as expected.

Also another question related to profile, if i set a profile while building do i need to change that for every environment?

Error I get

```
[ERROR][error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#configurationDescriptorBuilding threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Model cl
asses are defined for the default persistence unit, but no default datasource was found. The default EntityManagerFactory will not be created. To solve this, configure the default datasource. Refer to https://qu
arkus.io/guides/datasource for guidance.
```

Comment: Quarkus does not  need to have all the connection informatio at build time. It is perfectly valid to leave out the URL and credentials at build time and only supply them at runtime

Comment: that is strange, if I do not give db details then I get above error, if I give db details then I have CredentialsProvider that get failed to initialized as jenkins does not access to aws.

Comment: That might be a bug. Can you open an issue with as many details as possible, and preferable attaching a small project that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: thanks will do that